# How to simplify code with repeated patterns?

Tags: macros

I have dozens of lines like this in my `.cls` file, with `theorem` replacing with `lemma`, `proposition`, `definition` and so on...

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{theorem}{O{}}{%
    \IfLanguageName{chinese}{\begin{theoremCN}[#1]}{}%
    \IfLanguageName{french}{\begin{theoremFR}[#1]}{}%
    \IfLanguageName{english}{\begin{theoremEN}[#1]}{}%
}{%
    \IfLanguageName{chinese}{\end{theoremCN}}{}%
    \IfLanguageName{french}{\end{theoremFR}}{}%
    \IfLanguageName{english}{\end{theoremEN}}{}%
}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{theorem*}{O{}}{%
    \IfLanguageName{chinese}{\begin{theoremCN*}[#1]}{}%
    \IfLanguageName{french}{\begin{theoremFR*}[#1]}{}%
    \IfLanguageName{english}{\begin{theoremEN*}[#1]}{}%
}{%
    \IfLanguageName{chinese}{\end{theoremCN*}}{}%
    \IfLanguageName{french}{\end{theoremFR*}}{}%
    \IfLanguageName{english}{\end{theoremEN*}}{}%
}
```

Code like this takes up almost 400 lines, is there any way to simplify it? (I remember seeing others write something like `\csname...`, but I wasn't able to working out for detail)

Comment: Perhaps `\newcommand\chineseSC{CN}
\newcommand\frenchSC{FR}
\newcommand\englishSC{EN}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{theorem}{O{}}{%
  \begin{theorem\csname\languagename SC\endcsname}[#1]
}{%
  \end{theorem\csname\languagename SC\endcsname}[#1]
}`

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and assume that the you have something like:

```
\newtheorem{theoremEN}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{theoremFR}{Théorème}
\newtheorem{theoremCN}{定理}
```

But the fact that you're doing something based on language is a hint that we want to take advantage of Babel's multilingual functionality.

We would define our theorem environment by doing something like

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{\theoremname}
\newcommand{\theorem}{} % So we can redefine it with \renewcommand
```

Then we would be able to add to the language hooks doing something like this:

```
\addto\extrasenglish{%
  \renewcommand{\theoremname}{Theorem}
 }
 \addto\extrasfrench{%
   \renewcommand{\theoremname}{Théorème}
 }
 \addtoextraschinese{%
   \renewcommand{\theoremname}{定理}
 }
```

and get the appropriate theorem labels based on the language.

Having distinct numbering by language would be a little more challenging: We would want to have counters to save the current theorem number for each language:

```
\newcounter{theoremEN}
\newcounter{theoremCN}
\newcounter{theoremFR}
```

Then we save the value when we leave the language

```
\addto\noextrasenglish{\setcounter{theoremEN}{\value{theorem}}}
etc.
```

and restore it when we select the language

```
\addto\extrasenglish{\setcounter{theorem}{\value{theoremEN}}}
etc.
```

Usual disclaimer: I'm doing this off the top of my head. I've tested none of this.